Reloading nginx in windows is slow. Till the time it reloads, it is hitting the highest available path
When reloading nginx in windows after placing new configuration, it is hitting the highest possible for sometime until it reloads the new configuration.
Is there a way to wait till reload is completed or is there a way to reload nginx in faster manner?
Steps to reproduce:

Start nginx using the command <path to nginx binary> -c <path to nginx.conf>(Note: Please use the configuration given below)

Confirm that location we are hitting is not registered with nginx, so it hits the root location(/) curl --location http://localhost:8080/test

Place the given test.conf into the conf.d directory of nginx

Reload and hit the url at the same time by running the commands together.


<path to nginx binary> -c <path -s reload
curl --location http://localhost:8080/test

Observation: Root location will be hit

Wait few seconds and try hitting the same url again.

Observation: This time it will hit the configured location
Sample nginx.conf:
worker_processes  2;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
            default_type text/html;
            content_by_lua_block {
                ngx.say("<p>Root location</p>")
            }
        }

        include conf.d/*.conf;
    }
}

Sample test.conf:
location /test {
    content_by_lua_block {
        ngx.say("<p>Hello World</p>")
    }
}

